# Xamarin, Android: Lock Aspect Ratio to 16:9

Tags: android

We are working on an app that mainly uses either Framelayouts or Linearlayouts. 
In our app, we provide 5 different folders with drawables, from mdpi to xxxhdpi.

Working with weights or DisplayDimensions made our app look the exact same on basically every smartphone device. 
Every smartphone device, but one. The Samsung S8.

The problem is as seen below:

This is the main menu on almost any other device (S3, S4, S5, S6 -Edge, S7 - Edge)
[image]

This right here, is a screenshot of the mainmenu on the S8:
[image].

Removing the bottom buttons and displaying the app in fullscreen makes this even worse!

So what is going on here?
Simple - the S8 uses the same width (1440px) as the S7 for instance, but yet its screen is higher. Increasing the screen height without the width changes the aspect ratio.

While most smartphones use a ratio of 16:9, the S8 is somewhere at 20.5:9 I believe. Ergo: The screen DO NOT look the way they are supposed to.

Now theres gotta be a solution to that, which won't have us redisign almost every activity to ALSO fit the s8.

What optins are there?
Is there maybe an option in VISUAL STUDIO, to "lock" the aspect ratio to 16:9 and display maybe a black bar on top instead of streching the layout?

I hope you guys can help us! That'd be great!

Thank you!

Btw: I noticed that the apps that we made in unity which are usually games DO look the same. There the aspect ratio is maintained and a black bar is shown on the sides. This I hope, is possible for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround, that is pretty easy.

```
        if (Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels >= 2560)
        {
            intHeightOfDisplay = 2560;
        }
        else
        {
            intHeightOfDisplay = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
        }
```

Basically saying, that if the height of the display is heigher than "most phones" I just set it to the maximum height of my app. This works pretty much everywhere.

Comment: it is simply an global int for the class to be used later in the context.